# Why is there no StrongReference object?

Tags: java, memory-management, reference

I'm implementing some behavior which could benefit from using weak references some of the time.  I'd like the user of the class to be able to indicate at construction time whether this is the case or not.  Since `WeakReference` extends `Reference` at first glance it would seem I could do something like (this is a mockup, not what I'm actually trying to do):

```
public class Container<T> {
    private boolean useWeakRef;
    private Reference<T> ref;

    public Container(boolean isWeak) {
        useWeakRef = isWeak;
    }

    public void store(T val) {
        if(useWeakRef) {
            ref = new WeakReference<>(val);
        } else {
            ref = new StrongReference<>(val);
        }
    }

    // May return null
    public T get() {
        return ref.get();
    }
}
```

However there is no `StrongReference` class, and according to the [Reference javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html):

> Because reference objects are implemented in close cooperation with the garbage collector, this class may not be subclassed directly.

So I can't create my own subclass of Reference that holds a strong (i.e. normal) reference to the object.  This seems to mean it's not possible to make a class which hides whether it uses Weak (or Soft) references from the caller.

I don't really understand why this class doesn't exist, a `StrongReference` object should simply always return the object from get() unless clear() has been called.  Why is this missing?  Is a `StrongReference` inconsistent with `Reference` in some way?  It would make building generic reference-holder objects much simpler.

Comment: its also trivial to implement an interface for that functionality if you really need it.

Comment: Yes, I realize there are workarounds, but I assume the Java designers intentionally avoided including this seemingly logical class, and I'm wondering why they did so.

Comment: +1. There is also AtomicReference, which is a strong and thread-safe reference, but it does not implement the same interface.

Comment: I would venture that you assume too much :-) maybe in a future version after Oracle sells Java to someone who cares. Anyway +1 for the developer angst.

Comment: References are designed for when a normal reference variable is "too strong." Given Reference's purpose to exist, a StrongReference doesn't make sense. Abstracting the type of reference is gibberish since a data stricture either contains references to objects, or contains references to objects where the targets may or may not be garbage collected. Either you have code to reload them, or you don't. If you may need to reload the objects, why not just use weak references?

Comment: There is no way for us to answer your "why" Question.  I suggest that you email James Gosling, and see if he is willing to satisfy your curiosity.  Meanwhile, the Question is non-constructive.

Comment: In my opinion "why did the designers go with implementation X" questions can be perfectly constructive.  Example, Why do Guava's weakKey MapMaker objects use `==` instead of `.equals()`?  The answer is because it's somewhat inconsistent and error-prone to use `.equals()` in tandem with weak references, but their documentation to that effect isn't terribly clear.

Comment: @dimo414: I guess they used `==` instead if `.equals` to avoid spontaneous NullPointerExceptions in cases like key1.equals(key2) when key1 has already been garbage collected.

Comment: @chhh no the issue is that a weak reference is an identity relationship (i.e. a weak reference doesn't persist simply because other, `equal` objects are referenced, only if the exact object the weak reference refers to is referenced elsewhere) therefore using `.equals()` to compare weak keys doesn't make sense.  My point was (and you've somewhat confirmed it) that it's fair to ask such questions.

Comment: Instead of one class that conditionally uses two types of references, why not write `WeakContainer` and `StrongContainer`, both implementing or extending `Container`?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede as mentioned, `Container` is just a mockup to demonstrate the problem.  It's not a pattern I'm actually trying to use.

Comment: Instead of `Reference<T>` one could use a `Supplier<T>` and then call `ref = useWeakRef ? new WeakReference<>(val)::get : ()->val;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava's `LocalCache` uses a [`StrongValueReference`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/1670960e088fe9c1e78b5d7dd7c0505741bf2988/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#L1676) class which replicates what I'd want a `StrongReference` class to do.  While it's too bad Guava doesn't expose this as a public class, I take this as a confirmation that this is a missing feature from the JDK, and that it's OK to replicate it when necessary.

That said, most use cases that need to abstract the type of references they're working with will likely be able to use [Guava's `Cache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) behavior directly, like I was.  I'd encourage anyone coming across this question to explore Guava's existing caching mechanisms before reinventing this abstract reference behavior themselves.

Answer (score 4):

When i've needed to do this, i just created a custom Reference interface and a trivial subclass of WeakReference.  it's annoying but it's about as good as you can do.

```
public interface MyReference<T> {
  public T get();
}

public class MyWeakReference<T> extends WeakReference<T> implements MyReference<T> {
}

public class MyStrongReference<T> implements MyReference<T> {
  // obvious implementation here ...
}
```

UPDATE:

to clarify, i have no idea *why* this wasn't included in the jdk in the first place (i, too, wish it had been), however, i feel this is a reasonable workaround.

for those seeking justification of this idea, i have found it necessary when implementing custom caches where the strength of the reference is part of the configuration for the cache.

Comment: This doesn't answer the Question.  The Question is asking WHY the Java developers haven't implemented this.

Comment: @StephenC - true, that is part of the question.  however, the part that says "This seems to mean it's not possible to make a class which hides whether it uses Weak (or Soft) references from the caller" seems to imply a desire for a "solution" to the problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot subclass Reference because it does not have any public / protected constructors. But there's a workaround:

```
class StrongReference<T> extends WeakReference<T> {
    private final T referent;

    StrongReference(T referent) {
        super(null);
        this.referent = referent;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        return referent;
    }

    // implement other methods
}
```

Comment: That looks very hackish to me. Inheritance describes an "is a" relationship, and you'll have a hard time arguing that a `StrongReference` "is a" `WeakReference` :)

Comment: Agreed.  The implementation I was using (before I switched to Guava) was a wrapper `StrongOrWeakReference<T>` that held either a `WeakReference<T>` or a `T` directly, depending on how the object was constructed, and implemented `get()` and `clear()`.

Comment: @creinig: I'm pretty sure that a strong reference is a superset of a weak reference, actually.  Not only does it allow you to find the object, as a weak reference does, it also keeps it alive / prevents garbage collection on it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But the entire point of a WeakReference is that it allows the GC to collect the referenced instance. Having StrongReference inherit from WeakReference would mean that you can pass a StrongReference to any client expecting a WeakReference, i.e. you can pass something with exactly the opposite of the expected behavior. That doesn't make particular sense :)

Comment: @creinig: A client expecting a weak reference can be passed a strong reference, just like a client expecting a 32-bit integer can be passed an 8 bit integer, or a client expecting `int?` can be passed `int`.